# What Entities are visible in Cross <script> block in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I was trying to figure out what entities (ex. variable, property, function, object, etc.) defined in one `<script>` block would be visible to other `<script>` block.

After some study, it seems to me that:

1. From one `<script>` block, only the variables/properties that are attached with global `window` object, are accessible to other `<script>` block.
2. For a function/object or expression to be accessed to other `<script>` block, it must be attached to the `window` object by means of a variable/property.
3. Variables that are defined outside any function scope with/without `var` keyword, become part of `window` object/global context.
4. Variables defined inside a function without `var` keyword, become part of `window` object/global context.
5. **There is no other ways to be inside the `window` object/global context** and thus accessible to cross `<script>` block.

I know the fifth point is pretty bold, but it seemed correct to me.

**Is this correct?** If not, what's wrong?

Comment: What's the difference between (1) and (2)? Please provide **code examples** for each point - this is a programming forum after all.

Answer (score 2):

`window` is global. Everything else is local to the current closure (which in JS is the current function, not the current "block"). Undeclared variables (those without `var`) become properties of the `window` and are therefore globally accessible. `window` is implied when a local variable can't be found (so `location` will either give the contents of a local variable called `location`, if there is one, or `window.location` otherwise).

Answer (score 0):

All SCRIPT blocks of a web-page share the same global object. Therefore, if one SCRIPT block defines a global variable/function, all *subsequent* SCRIPT blocks will be able to access it.

The global object is referenced by the `window` global variable.

---

In global code, all variables and function declarations become properties of the global object:

```
var x;

function fn () {}
```

Here, you can access the `x` variable with `x`, or `window.x`, `self.x`. Same goes for `fn`.

---

In function code, local variables and nested functions *do not* become properties of the global object:

```
function fn () {
    var local_x;
    function local_fn () {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> From one  block, only the variables/properties that are attached with global window object, are accessible to other  block.

Wrong. Every property in [host objects](http://es5.github.com/#x4.3.7) or [built-in objects](http://es5.github.com/#x4.3.6) is accessible. This includes the global object, but also things like `Function.prototype`.

> For a function/object or expression to be accessed to other  block, it must be attached to the window object by means of a variable/property.

No. As stated above, it can be attached anywhere. Or even stored in localStorage, cookie etc.

> Variables that are defined outside any function scope with/without var keyword, become part of window object/global context.
>
> Variables defined inside a function without var keyword, become part of window object/global context.

I know what you mean, but let's be precise: Variables cannot be defined without `var` keyword. You are talking about implicitly accessing properties of the global object. And yes, using `var` outside a function does so too.

Comment: Thank you for your very precise answer. Ohh.. I have really missed the host objects.